CKEditor5 image not resize correctly
i try using ckeditor5 but  image not resize correctly..
I insert the image through ckeditor5 and it changes to 200 pixels, but ckeditor generates this code
<figure class="image image_resized" style="width:200px;">
    <img style="aspect-ratio:1280/720;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64 etc etc.." width="1280" height="720">
</figure>

And browsers are respecting the width of the img tag

From the documentation on this page, you need to include css styles for the content.
For example:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/42.0.0/ckeditor5-content.css">

<div class="ck-content">
  <figure class="image image_resized" style="width:200px;">
      <img style="aspect-ratio:1280/720;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64 etc etc.." width="1280" height="720">
  </figure>
</div>


This answer could be improved by quoting some of the relevant documentation (using a > quote block) and explaining how it enforces the size of the image when the img node specifies the width as 1280 and the parent node has a style of width:200px;.
